# Pass data in Angular Form Group

Tags: angular

I have an angular reactive forms, and An array of data. I want to pass one of array data in this forms.
**the FormGroup**

```
this.paiement = this.ajp.group({
  nbrmois: ['', [Validators.required]],
  mantant: [''],
  idUser: [''],
  paiementTime: ['']
})
```

**Array of data**

```
  this.nbrs = [
          {
            nom: '3 mois',
            prix: 200,
            dis: '0 %',
            valueq: 3
          },
          {
            nom: '6 mois',
            prix: 540,
            dis: '10 %',
            valueq: 6
          },
        ]
```

I tried with `'nbrmois: [this.nbrs.valueq.value, [Validators.required]]`, but doesn't work

Comment: nbrmois: [this.nbrs[0].valueq, [Validators.required]],  ........ you have array, so you need use index of array, witch element do you wannt to show. If you wannt show all element in array then you need use **formArray** element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are asking is "Can I update a FormArray with patch or on init", the answer is no. You have to iterate through your collection and push formGroups to solve this.

```
nbrs = [
  {
    nom: '3 mois',
    prix: 200,
  }
]
nbrmoisArray = new FormArray([])
form = new FormGroup({
  nbrmois: this.nbrmoisArray
})
this.nbrs.forEach(x => {
  const {nom, prix} = x;
  this.nbrmoisArray.push(new FormGroup({
    nom: new FormControl(nom),
    prix: new FormControl(prix)
  })
}
```

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="nbrmois">
    <div *ngFor="let group of nbrmoisArray.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]='i'>
        <input formControlName="nom" />
        <input formControlName="prix" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```